# dimension of an affine variety over $ \mathbb C.$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, krull-dimension

Consider the polynomials $f,g,h \in \mathbb C [x_1, \dots,x_n]$ defined by

$ f(x)=x_1^2 + \cdots + x_{n-2}^2, \quad g(x)=x_{n-1},$ and $ h(x)=x_n.$

> How can I compute the dimension of the variety
>
> $$ V \subset \mathbb A_{\mathbb C}^n: f=g=h=0 ?$$

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you want to find out the Krull dimension of the ring $$\mathbb C [x_1, \dots,x_n]/(x_1^2 + \cdots + x_{n-2}^2,x_{n-1},x_n)\simeq\mathbb C [x_1, \dots,x_{n-2}]/(x_1^2 + \cdots + x_{n-2}^2)$$ which is $n-3$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick answer. I have two questions:              1. this quotient that you take is the affine coordinate ring of the variety, right? How do you see that it has dimensio $n-3 ?   2. If I want to find the dimension in terms of the minimum dimension of the tangent spaces, how would I work ? And in this case the result is the same ? Thank you in advance!

Comment: 1. Yes, this is the dimension of the affine coordinate ring. For any ideal $I$ in a finitely generated algebra over a field $A$ which is an integral domain we have $\dim A/I=\dim A-\operatorname{height}I$. (See [here](http://www.math.iitb.ac.in/atm/caag1/ghorpade.pdf), Corollary 1.5.)

Comment: The pdf in the link seems very good, thank's! Do you also have any idea regarding the first question or any link like the previous one ?

Comment: I suppose you are referring to the second question. No, I don't know how to compute the dimension as you suggested. (Btw, your variety is a hypersurface in the $(n-2)$-dimensional affine space, so geometrically it's pretty clear that its dimension is the dimension of the space minus one.)

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg: I just saw his second reply. I was just waiting to close the conversation that's all. I acceept it now.

Comment: @user26857: thank's for your second comment also ! I was just curious to see how one could apply this characterization about the dimension, in practice. It seems to me more complicated in practice, rather than the algebraic one.

Comment: Dear passenger: you are absolutely right: sorry for having rushed you.